# How to enable Google Authenticator over sshd when already using public key?

Tags: ssh, google-authenticator

I'm running Debian Jessie on a VPS.

I want to enable both private key and Google Authenticator to get into the server via SSH.

I enabled

> auth       required     pam_google_authenticator.so

in *both* /etc/pam.d/sshd and common-auth

It works when I log in using the "terminal" (using a VNC provided by the VPS provider), but when I ssh in, it just lets me through without prompting me for Google Authenticator.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `sshd` is even using PAM stack  (`UsePam` option in `sshd_config`).

Then make sure that PAM authentication is required by your configuration (PAM password authentication part is skipped if publickey authentication method succeeds). You can do that by setting appropriate `AuthenticationMethods` in `sshd_config`.